# Не могу типизировать dispatch в MapDispatchToProps с thunk внутри

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

Столкнулся с проблемой когда типизировал MapDispatchToProps:

```
const mapDispatch = (dispatch: Dispatch<ThunkAction<Promise<void>, TStore, unknown, TActions>>) => ({
makeReq: (index: string) => dispatch(ApiReq(index)) })
```

Thunk:

```
export const ApiReq = (index: string): ThunkAction<Promise<void>, TStore, unknown, TActions> => {
    return async dispatch => {
        const responce = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + index)
        const json = await responce.json()
        dispatch(ReqActionCreator(await json))
    }
}
```

Выдает ошибку: Тип "ThunkAction<...>" не удовлетворяет ограничению "Action". Какой тип должен быть у dispatch?

Answer (score 0):

я понял, не нужно было обворачивать в mapDispatchToProps:

```
const makeReq = (index: string) => ApiReq(index)
```